# Can I reference the document itself in an elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to get all documents where the value of fieldA is greater than the value of fieldB. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Kind of like this:

```
body: {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: {
        range: {
          "fieldA": { gt: "this.fieldB" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do it is by indexing `fieldC` with the value of `fieldA - filedB` and using a range filter to find all records with `fieldC` greater than `0`. It can be also a boolean field that will have `true` if `fieldA` is greater than `fieldB` and `false` otherwise.

If reindexing is not an option it's possible to use [script filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html) to perform this check, but it will essentially mean a full index scan for every search, so it is not going to scale.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. Could you provide a link to documentation about how to set up an index that way?

Comment: It used to be possible using [transform scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html) but since they are [going away in 2.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/12674) it's better to implement this calculation in your ingestion code just before sending the record to elasticsearch for indexing.